# Visual Artifact on Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, external-display, visual-studio-code

Windows: windows 10 home (latest update)
Graphics Card: RTX 2060 (driver updated)
RAM: 2×8GB

I am having this artifact. And It is just random. I don't know why.. If I move the cursor to it, it vanishes.
N.B: I use other apps and even tried split screen, this artifact only appears on VSCode only.
Please show me the way to resolve it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2865.jpg)

Comment: Artifacts like that are typically caused by hardware faults

Comment: I am having this issue too, on separate monitors, it happens in slack and vscode. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I disabled hardware acceleration in VS Code

To add this flag:

```
Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
Run the Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments command.
This command will open a argv.json file to configure runtime arguments. You might see some default arguments there already.
Add "disable-hardware-acceleration": true.
Restart VS Code.
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40

Comment: Your link should be pointing at [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration)

Answer (score 0):

Update: Try doing a fresh install of the latest version of Visual Studio or try switching to a different theme to seem if you get the same problem. (05-18-2020)

Not sure if this will be any help at all but I came across this article: [5 Ways to Fix a Stuck Pixel on Your Scree](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-software-solutions-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-your-lcd-monitor/):

*Is It a Stuck or Dead Pixel?
So what if you spot an odd pixel? Is what you’re seeing just a stuck pixel or is it, in fact, a dead pixel?
A stuck pixel will appear in any of the colors that its three sub-pixels can form, i.e. red, green, or blue. In a dead pixel, all sub-pixels are permanently off, which will make the pixel appear black.
The cause could be a broken transistor. In rare cases, however, even a black pixel may just be stuck.
So if you’re seeing a colored or white pixel, you might be able to fix it. And if you see a black pixel, chances are low, but there is still hope.*

It recommends using this guide to do a manual repair if a software solution doesn't work: [How to Fix a Stuck Pixel on an LCD Monitor - wikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Stuck-Pixel-on-an-LCD-Monitor).

However considering the amount of what I assume are dead pixels mainly I'd be skeptical either guide will be of much use, but thought you should have the information.

Comment: No sir. This problem only occurs in this particular software. Other Softwares are running ok. Even in split-screen. So it might have nothing to do with the display or even windows may be. When they occur they automatically change to normal mostly when I hover the mouse pointer on those pixels and sometimes when I start typing. But this is really an annoying problem. Even I tried to reinstall the app from the scratch, but it is still the same :(
But I really appreciate your patient work for my problem. Thank you

Comment: Huh, maybe try doing a fresh install of the latest version of Visual Studio or try switching to a different theme to seem if you get the same problem

Comment: I've also seen this in the League of Legends login, Docker desktop app and other Microsoft apps... I think it might be related to other issues as @invrt suggests